# Question involving relation between directional derivative and the gradient of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Prove or disprove the following statement:
Suppose a function has all its directional derivatives $$D_\hat{p}f$$ exist at a point $$(a,b)$$, then $$D_\hat{p}f(a, b) = (\nabla f)(a,b)\cdot \hat{p}$$

I think that this is false and hence need to provide a counterexample. Could you give an example such that
the directional derivative exist but the gradient doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient consists of directional derivatives. Hence, there is no example for what you are asking.

However, what you are actually looking for is a function which has all directional derivatives, such that the formula
\begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}D_{\hat p}f (a,b)=\nabla f(a,b)\cdot\hat p\end{equation}
is not satisfied.

A possible example is the function $$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} & \mbox{for}\ (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\ 0 &\mbox{for}\ (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
One can easily check the following properties:

- The partial derivative of $f$ exist and vanish at $(0,0)$, hence $\nabla f(0,0)=0$.
- All directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ exist. If $\hat p=(p_x,p_y)\ne (0,1)$ we have
  $$ D_{\hat p}(0,0)=\frac{p_y^2}{p_x}. $$

Hence, $(\star)$ can't hold, since $\nabla f(0,0)\cdot \hat{p} = 0$ for any $\hat p$.

Edit: The statements follow directly from below calculation:

> For $\hat p = (p_x,p_y)$ we have $$ D_{\hat p} f(0,0)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon p_x,\epsilon p_y)-f(0,0)}{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{p_xp_y^2}{p_x^2+\epsilon^2p_y^4}.$$